# Probability formula for repeated numbers after 3 draws, in Pick 5 of 31

Tags: probability

This formula was given to me by a gifted young lady to determine the probability of the number of repeated numbers from the previous three draws in a pick $5$ of $31$ game. The history of $5566$ draws so far I'm comparing to seems to indicate the formula may be wrong, as it is far from the results of the formula. Can anyone determine if this formula is correct?

---

$n =$ number of distinct numbers among the last three draws(usually $12-15$ but I've seen it as low as $9$), $x =$ number of repeats ($0-5$).  As an example, $15$ distinct numbers among the previous three draws, probability of having $5$ repeats in next draw...the formula determines an $8.8$% chance, but the $5566$ draws so far indicate it has actually happened only $.07$%.

---

($5 * n! * 26! * (31-n)! * 26!) / (31! * (n-x)! * (26-n+x)! * 31!$)

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Well, maybe you have to know what "pick 5 of 31" means.  I think you'll get a better response if you explain the rules of the game.

Comment: Pick 5 lottery numbers from 1-31. Wisconsin Badger 5.

Comment: I believe the formula is attempting to quantify bias in the number selection. Your trials result is confirmation that there is no bias in the selection.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. n is known,,usually 12-15. x can be specified as 0-5. Obviously 5 is where the greatest interest lies..what is the probability of the next draw containing 5 numbers from the set of n numbers that comprise the last three draws? This significantly reduces the number of combinations to consider playing, although the likelihood (probability) of it occurring is also reduced. Just trying to put an accurate number on it.

Comment: Probability of x repeats with n distinct numbers = 
26!/31!   *   n!/(n-x)!   *  (31-n)!/(26-n+x)!   *  5!/(x! *(5-x)!

Answer (score 0):

You say that the given 15 distinct numbers in the previous 3 draws, the formula gives $0.088$ as the probability of 5 repeated numbers, but the actual probability should be 
$$\frac{15 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11}{31 \cdot 30 \cdot 29 \cdot 28 \cdot 27}=0.017$$
This event should only occur about 1 percent of the time.